# Twig Number Format converts double to int

Tags: twig

I'm trying to print the difference between two numbers.

When printed directly both numbers have a value assigned to them and have a comma as decimal seperator:

```
{{ vals[1] }} --> 7,00
{{ vals[2] }} --> 6,63
```

to actually be able to calculate with those numbers I'm replacing the `,` seperator with a `.` using the `|number_format (2, '.', ',')`. However when I now print those numbers directly I get an int value

```
{{ vals[1]|number_format (2, '.', ',') }} --> 7.00
{{ vals[2]|number_format (2, '.', ',') }} --> 6.00
```

therefore trying to calculate the difference of those values I only get int values in return.

```
{% set diff = vals[1]|number_format(2, '.', ',') - vals[2]|number_format(2, '.', ',') %} --> 1.00
```

Comment: why not calculate the diff before, and after that print the result with number_format ?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the diff before I print the result. The values themself come from a data sql query and I printed them out to see what's causing the issue and where the double to int switch happens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason I was unable to set the correct comma seperator using `number_format`. I ended up using `replace` instead:

```
 {% set diff = (vals[1]|replace({',': '.'}) - vals[2]|replace({',': '.'})) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using twigs [`number_format`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html) is a direct mapping to [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) (with type casting):

```
return number_format((float) $number, $decimal, $decimalPoint, $thousandSep);
                     ^^^^^^^
```

Ref: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/3.x/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php#L569

---

What you're supplying is a string `"6,63"`, so ultimately what get's passed to the *native* `number_format` is: `6.00` because of the type casting result.

Ref: https://3v4l.org/Md12f

---

So if you want to use `number_format` in your views, make sure to pass proper `int`s or `float`s. Otherwise *embrace* the value being a string and use string manipulation methods (as in your answer).

Answer (score 0):

This example should work:

```
{% set val1 = '7,00'  %}
{% set val2 = '6,63'  %}

{% set val1 = val1|replace({',': '.'})  %}
{% set val2 = val2|replace({',': '.'})  %}

 result = {{ (val1 - val2)|round (2) }}

// output: 0.37
```

Comment: thanks hous, that's what I'm using now, see in the other answers.